# What's up with the Class::get(id) idiom in PHP

Tags: programming-languages, php

I am a new PHP developer (coming from .NET). The experienced php dev that I work with said that calling a static get method on a PHP class with an ID as a parameter is common in PHP.

Is there a name for this idiom? Is there a reason why developers do this? Can someone point to a link to an example class?

I would like to understand more of what he is saying. He is talking about code like this I think, to pull car #1 from the database:

```
$car = Car::get(1)
```

Comment: Seems to be bound to some framework. Some ActiveRecord or ORM library?

Comment: It _is_ called [active record pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern). :)

Comment: @CodeCaster This might be an example of active record under the hood, but the same _pattern_ is used for other things as well (validtion, input, so on and so forth). If we're talking about [Laravel](http://laravel.com) then they are actually using the [facade pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) under the hood. Accessing it via static methods (and magic methods) is just [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar).

Answer (score 1):

This is the [facade pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) and the purpose is to provide easy access to common or otherwise complicated tasks. Generally it just provides [syntatic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar). To compare it to the C# world think of it like extension methods:

Example of calculating the total transaction amount for a user traditionally:

```
var total = 0f;
foreach(var transaction in User.transactions) {
    total += transaction.Amount;
}
```

Using an extension method:

```
// Extension Method
public static float AccountBalance(this User user) {
    var total = 0f;
    foreach(var transaction in User.transactions) {
        total += transaction.Amount;
    }
    return total;
}

// Using the extension method
user.AccountBalance();
```

Likewise the same sort of thing happens using the facade pattern in PHP:

```
$total = 0;
foreach($user->trasnactions as $transaction) {
    $total += $transaction->amount;
}
```

With a facade

```
<?php
class User {
    public static function TotalTransactionSum($userid) {
        $user = $userRepository->getById($userid);
        $total = 0;
        foreach($user->transaction as $transaction) {
            $total += $transaction->amount;
        }
        return $total;
    }
}

// Using the facade later
$total = User::TotalTransactionSum(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's called the [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) and it's generally a bad design practice.

I'm assuming when you call `Car::get(1)` on the data model for `Car` it uses a singleton reference for the data source, queries the database and returns the record.

This is bad design.

Singletons hide the dependencies of the data model in the source code. The `get()` method is made static to avoid passing around an object reference. This creates fractures in the connection between business logic and data models.

It's just a really bad thing to do if this is how you're accessing your data.

- It violates the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://www.oodesign.com/single-responsibility-principle.html) because your models handle their own creation.
- It creates tightly coupled code that is difficult to maintain.
- It makes it very difficult to unit test.
- The data models state is changed by multiple points in the source code outside the scope of the current caller.
- The data models carry state changes into other business rules.

I could go on and on...

Comment: Not always, it might be the Factory pattern. Maybe the Car class returns an object of a different class, according to a lookup table and identified by the id passed - e.g. `Car::get(1)` returns `new Ferrari()`, `Car::get(2)` returns `new Mercedes()`, etc.

Comment: @Benubird +1 good point. I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: In this case it's likely a database access pattern. `Car::get(0)` will return a `Car` instance representing the database entry/entries tied to Car ID 0, and so on. I'm not sure I'd call it a factory, but it's the same sort of idea. Some awful home-grown ORM, I'd guess.

Comment: I am faced with these kind of objects in java at the moment and I can tell that they are horrible and nearly impossible to test properly.